# Is equality of cardinality of stages within a limit constructible stage always witnessed locally in that stage?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

In Gödel's constructible universe $L$, we have: $|L_\alpha|= |\alpha|$ is provable internally in $L$ for every infinite ordinal $\alpha$.

Now let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal and we have infinite ordinals $\beta, \gamma < \alpha \land |\beta|=|\alpha| \land |\gamma|=|\alpha|$.

> Is it always the case that the bijection witnessing $|L_\beta|= |L_\gamma|$ is an element of $L_\alpha$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Not at all. Take any $L_\alpha$ such that:

1. $\alpha$ is countable, and
2. $L_\alpha\cong M\prec L_{\omega_2}$.

Then there is some $\beta<\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\models\beta=\omega_1$. In particular, $L_\alpha$ will not recognise any bijection between $\beta$ and smaller ordinals, so if $\gamma<\beta$, $$L_\alpha\models|L_\gamma|=|\gamma|<|\beta|=|L_\beta|.$$
And all three ordinals are just countable.

Comment: so the bijection witnessing the countability of all of these three ordinals in your answer would lie at a stage higher than $L_\alpha$

Comment: Indeed. That's how it goes.

Comment: a closely related question, can we arrange to have internal bijections within $L_\alpha$ for some stages of it? I mean infinite ones of course that are bijective to $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is limit.

Comment: Take a slightly larger countable ordinal, where $L_\alpha$ does have a definable bijection with $\omega$, for example.

Comment: a less ambitious alternative, would it be feasible to have a stage $L_\alpha$ for *some* countable limit $\alpha> \omega$ such that any two infinite elements of $L_\alpha$ have a bijection that is an element of $L_\alpha$? Or that is impossible?

Comment: @Zuhair: Of course. Take $\alpha$ such where $L_\alpha$ knows its countable. Or, any $L_\alpha\cong M\prec L_{\omega_1}$.